# Capturing variable names from a select

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the back end I have written some code that reads through a file and outputs to a list of JavaScript arrays for example, the page will see:

```
<script>
  var peanuts = ["1","s","g","3","n"];
  var cashewNuts = ["d","a","f","d","n"];
  var PecanNuts = ["6","m","3","x","m"];
  var BrazilNuts = ["j","n","7","v","s"];
  var goingNuts = ["a","e","7","m","y"];
</script>
```

I then want to use an array based on the value of a  somewhere else in that page.

So for example:

```
if($('select').val()===0){
   alert(firstArray[1]);
}
```

My issue is that the variable names are decided on what is contained in the read file, I can't know this information. Is there a way to say for example

```
//collect the value from the select and assign it to a var
var varN = $('select').val();
//then collect another variable that has the variable name that 
//equals the value of the 'varN'
```

I know this seems horrendous but unfortunately based on what I need to do, it is what I need to do :(

Comment: can you provide expected output? for your sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If for example your vars are in the global scope, you can do

`var val = window[varN][0];` to get peanuts:1

If you do

```
var nuts = {
  peanuts : ["1","s","g","3","n"],
  cashewNuts : ["d","a","f","d","n"],
  PecanNuts : ["6","m","3","x","m"],
  BrazilNuts : ["j","n","7","v","s"],
  goingNuts : ["a","e","7","m","y"]
}
```

then you can use

```
var val = nuts[varN][0];
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you, I just feel a little dirty doing it this way - but lousy on the backend means lousy on the front. Thank you!

Comment: @Phish I agree, you should accept his answer now instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are declared directly in `<script>`, you can use `window[varN]`.